# Why is Blank Space affecting my SQL statement Result?

Tags: sql, regex

I am learning SQL wherein I read that blank spaces doesn't affect the results but i tried this code

```
SELECT name 
FROM items 
WHERE name REGEXP '[^12345] boxes of frogs'
```

it gives me the result:

```
48 boxes of frogs
 7 boxes of frogs
```

and when I run this code on same table

```
SELECT name 
FROM items 
WHERE name REGEXP '[^12345]boxes of frogs'
```

It gives me the result:

```
 3 boxes of frogs
48 boxes of frogs
 7 boxes of frogs
```

So my question is that why blank space is affecting my result?

Comment: Do you mean `3boxes of frogs` instead of `3 boxes of frogs`?

Comment: Spaces in strings do matter.

Comment: @juergend i want boxes of frogs other than 1,2,3,4,5 boxes of frogs.

Comment: @MrTux but then why in the result of second query 3 boxes of frogs is coming??

Comment: It's not the space between SELECT and name which makes the difference. It's The "missing" space after `[^12345]`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am learning SQL from videos by thenewboston.org where he made a database of items to teach the SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by the regexp - which is defined as a string and within strings spaces do matter! All in all, this is more about regexp than SQL ;)

`[^12345]` matches one character which is not 1,2,3,4 or 5, thus, it matches SPACE.

`'[^12345] boxes of frogs'` matches all rows with names which have no 1,2,3,4 or 4 directly before `boxes of frogs` (notice the space directly before `boxes`).

```
"36 boxes of frogs" -> matches
"3 boxes of frogs" -> not matched
```

`'[^12345]boxes of frogs'` matches `3 boxes of frogs` because `[^12345]` matches SPACE which is beween `3` and `boxes of frogs`.

```
"36 boxes of frogs" -> matches
"3 boxes of frogs" -> matched
"3boxes of frogs" -> not matched
```

Hope it got clear...